# System Monitor is broken on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, system-monitor

and recently my system monitor has been bugging out. I haven't made any extensive changes to the os other than applying sweet theme and a Plymouth theme. I am attaching a gif showing what happens to the system monitor.[Gif recording of the system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ERY7.gif)